# Form of periodic function involving exponential

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am trying to prove that if the function $f(z)= a_{1}e^{\lambda_{1}z} + ... + a_{n}e^{\lambda_{n}z}$ is periodic of period $T \neq 0$  with $a_{i} \neq 0$ for every $i$, then $\lambda_{i} = 2k_{i}\pi i/T $ for some $k_{i} \in Z$  for every $i$. Any ideas?

Comment: If we were talking about, say, a sine function, it would have the form $\sin(\frac{2n\pi}{T} x)$ if it had a period  $T$ (it could, of course, have related periods).  So a complex exponential function would look like $e^{\frac{2n\pi}{T}iz}$.  For $f(z)$ to have the period $T$ then, we should be able to factor such an exponential function out of the sum.

Comment: I can factor an exponential but I can't prove that it has period T as the initial function.

Comment: That the period is $T$ is part of the premise.  You are asked to show what the $\lambda_i$'s have to be like if that is the case.

Comment: I might be reading wrong but the function that is periodic is $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}e^{\lambda_{k}z}$, not $\sum_{k\neq p}^{n} a_{k}e^{\lambda_{k}z}$, the fact that the first has period T does not imply that the second does.

Answer (score 2):

Not so sure!! Just a try ...

Let us suppose that $a_k \neq 0$ 
$$f(z+T) - f(z)  = 0\implies \sum_{k=1}^n a_k e^{\lambda_k z} ( e^{\lambda_k T} -1)= 0$$

if $\lambda_k = \frac{i 2\pi k}{T}$ the above condition holds. Conversely, suppose, for any arbitrary $n$ the above condition holds, and suppose if each $ e^{\lambda_k T}$ is not $1$, then there exists some $e^{\lambda_k T} -1 \neq 0$. Let us denote this by $ e^{\lambda_p T}$. Then $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^n a_k e^{\lambda_k z} ( e^{\lambda_k T} -1)= 0 \implies \sum_{k\neq p}^n a_k e^{\lambda_k z} ( e^{\lambda_k T} -1) = - a_p e^{\lambda_pz} (e^{\lambda_pT} - 1) \neq 0$ contradicting our assumption that summation holds for any arbitrany $n$. Hence each $ e^{\lambda_k T}$ must be equal to $1$ or $\lambda$ must be integer multiple of $i2\pi\over T$

Comment: Hi there, 

The problem in your argument is that you don't know if the function $ \sum_{k \neq p}^{n} a_{k}e^{\lambda_{k}z}$ is periodic with period T.

Comment: That the function has that period is the assumption; you are being asked to prove $f(z)$ periodic with period $T \ne 0 \Rightarrow \lambda_i = 2\pi k_i i/T$ ..

Comment: I might be reading wrong but the function that is periodic is $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}e^{\lambda_{k}z}$, not $\sum_{k\neq p}^{n} a_{k}e^{\lambda_{k}z}$, the fact that the first has period T does not imply that the second does.

Comment: @Frank you can choose $n$ arbitrarily. set $n = n-1$ so $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} a_{k}e^{\lambda_{k}z}$ is also periodic.

Comment: You are confusing the induction hypothesis, you can suppose that for all the periodic functions of period $T$ which can be expressed as the sum of $k$ terms of the form $a_{k}e^{\lambda_{k}z}$, $\lambda_{k}$ has the desired form for $k < n$. Then you should prove first that the function without a term has period T. 






If you were right we can apply your argument to simply say that if the function $f$ is periodic of period T, then every term is also periodic of period $T$, so we get the result.

Comment: @Frank what the flaw in this logic??

Comment: Where is this other sum you keep referring to?  Is there something omitted from your original statement?

Comment: Sorry guys, I could not check the forum before. Let me try to explain. We know that the function $\sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}e^{\lambda_{k}z}$ has period $T$. So crocodile suggest an induction argument. The case $n=1$ is clear. Then lets suppose that the proposition is true for all $m < n$, it means that for every function $g(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{m} b_{k}e^{\beta_{k}z}$ with $m<n$ and period $T$, such that $b_{k} \neq 0$ for every $k$, $\beta_{k}$ has the desired form.

Comment: In Crocodile's argument he uses the fact that the function $\sum_{k\neq p}^{n} a_{k}e^{\lambda_{k}z}$ (that is in fact a sum of $n-1$ terms) has period $T$. That's where I think the flaw is.

Comment: @RecklessReckoner I was referring to $\sum_{k \neq p}^{n} a_{k}e^{\lambda_{k}z}$, the fact that $f(z) = \sum_{k = 1}^{n} a_{k}e^{\lambda_{k}z}$ has period $T$ does not imply that $g(z) = \sum_{k \neq p}^{n} a_{k}e^{\lambda_{k}z}$ has period $T$.